# IE Script Error/JQuery Cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am working on a site and it works/looks great in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE8. For some reason when testing it in IE 6 and 7 the jQuery does not work (the images are there but static) I get the following error message:

Internet Explorer Script Error. 
Line: 38 
Char: 1
Error: Expected Identifier, string or number
Code: 0

Can someone help me out with this? Internet Exploder is killing me....

[www.telechoiceinc.com](http://www.telechoiceinc.com)

Comment: this is the url: www[dot]telechoiceinc[dot]com

Comment: You need to post the script that invokes your Cycle plugin, my guess is though you have an errant `,` in a config object somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

As i speculated above... you have trailing commas in your config objects. see my comments below.

```
$('#ourClientsRight').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 600,
        timeout: 4000,
        delay: 1000, // this comma should not be here
});
        $('#ourCarriers').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight',
        speed: 600,
        timeout: 7000,
        delay: 1000, // this comma should not be here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is all working now... often the smallest thing (a comma) breaks everything! Cheers!